# Top queryes in SQL Server 2000

Tags: performance, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to identify top resource consuming queries in SQL Server 2000.

Is thre a way to do that other than Sql profiler or a third party monitoring tool like Quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There weren't a lot of system views that would give you insight in SQL 2000. The way I've done this is with Profiler/Trace, run for a few days, group/sort queries. It's a pain, but I'm not sure what other methods (other than 3rd party) you can use here.

If you have an idea of queries that run long, you can examine query plans and statistics IO for reads and the load they might be putting on your server.

Comment: That's what i thought!

Answer (score 2):

Profiler or something like Spotlight for SQL Server from Quest will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that has been helpful for me in this regard:
http://vyaskn.tripod.com/analyzing_profiler_output.htm#booksNtools